# Does a child have to be both born and raised in Great Britain to be admitted to Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

I am a little confused about Hogwart's admission criteria.
**Does a child have to be both born and raised in GB to be admitted to Hogwarts?**

Would a child born outside of GB, whose family moved to England just before their 11th Birthday have their name in the [book of Admittance](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-quill-of-acceptance-and-the-book-of-admittance)?

What about a child born in GB and raised in another country?

Or a child who wasn't born in GB but spend a few years of their life there?

What if they "first exhibits signs of magic" (3rd paragraph in Pottermore) while on vacation abroad?

Comment: The problem is that you've probably spent more time writing this question than JKR spent thinking about how admissions work in the world of Potter.

Comment: The answer is probably no, but I can't find a definitive canon source that says where Seamus Finnigan was born and raised. He's Irish, supports the Ireland national Quidditch team, and supports an Irish league Quidditch team, so he's *probably* born and raised in Ireland, which isn't part of Great Britain.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - We're splitting hairs here. Ireland is part of the British Isles. There's every indication that The Ministry of Magic (and by extension Hogwarts) encompasses Ireland also, for example the fact that they manage the "*British and Irish Quidditch Leagues*"

Answer (score 3):

​

## Although it's been never directly addressed, it is quite plausible

Firstly, the only Wizarding schools that we know of are:

> **Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry** (Scotland)
>
> **Beauxbatons** Academy of Magic (France)
>
> **Castelobruxo** (Central Brazil)
>
> **Durmstrang** Institute (Northern Europe)
>
> **Ilvermorny** (Eastern North America)
>
> **Mahoutokoro School of Magic** (Japan)
>
> **Uagadou School of Magic** (Uganda)
>
> **Koldovstoretz** (Russia)
>
> *<sub>source: [here](https://brilliantmaps.com/wizard-school/)</sub>*

So, there are many countries and regions that don’t have their own Wizarding schools. It is highly plausible that wizarding kids could have been accepted at Hogwarts because, well, wizards have been known to live in other regions where there are no Wizarding schools.

About the fees structures, no one pays to go to Hogwarts; the only fees are those for textbooks and other necessary materials. In fact there is even a funding for those who cannot afford to buy those necessities.

Moreover, **Draco Malfoy** bragged about how he wished his father would send him to **Durmstrang** where there was no admittance for muggle-borns. So, it is the parents who decide where the kid should go.

So answering the first part of your question:

### It is not necessary to be born in the U.K to be accepted at Hogwarts. One could be born in America and if the parent/guardian submit application at Hogwarts (and it is accepted), they can.

**NOTE**: Hogwarts has also been known to have permanent exchange students as mentioned in the answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28039/are-there-canon-examples-of-students-permanently-transferring-from-one-school-to). So internationals admitted in Hogwarts (in a different way though) - **Possible**.

---

Speaking about *What if they "first exhibits signs of magic" while on vacation abroad?*

From the movie **Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone**, it is mentioned by Hagrid that Harry's name was added to the Hogwarts' list since the day he was born.

> **HAGRID**: A great Muggle like you is going to stop him?
>
> **HARRY**: Muggle?
>
> **HAGRID**: (to Harry) Non-magic folk. (*to Vernon*) ***This boy's had his name down since he were born***. He's going to the finest school of witchcraft and wizardry.

So, your school would send you an Owl accepting your admission at Hogwarts no matter where you are (*if of course you have been enrolled by your parents before coming of age*).

---

Comment: Hi! Thank you for taking the time for answering. I don't understand why you included the part about the other wizarding schools here, or the part about Harry being written in the Book of Admittance from birth (since it's not the case of every Hogwarts Students).

Comment: Do you have a source on Hogwarts accepting direct applications? I thought Hogwarts accepted only students whose name appears in the BoA, since JKR wrote : "These are the Quill of Acceptance and the Book of Admittance and they constitute the **only** process by which students are selected for Hogwarts"

Answer (score 2):

## Likely not - Leta’s father was French.

While most students attending Hogwarts are born and raised in Britain, Leta Lestrange attended Hogwarts, and it seems likely that she had been born in France, and spent the first few years of her life there. Her father, Corvus Lestrange Sr., was French.

> “**SCENE 100**
>   
> **EXT. PARK—1896—DAY**
>
> *We see a beautiful woman, LAURENA, dressed in an exquisite gown, walking through a park with her husband, MUSTAFA—clearly in love. A YOUNG YUSUF by their side.*
>
> **KAMA (V.O.)**
>   
> My mother, Laurena, was equally high-bred—a noted beauty. They were deeply in love. They knew a man of great influence, from a famous French pureblood family. He desired her.
>
> *Watching from a distance, an intense wizard, CORVUS LESTRANGE SR., studies her beauty.*” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald (The Original Screenplay)*</sup></sub>

While it is not stated clearly where Leta was born, since her father was French and her mother was forced to obey with the Imperius Curse, it seems likely she would have been born in France, where he was from and most likely living at the time.

> “**SCENE 101**
>   
> **INT. KAMA MANSION—1896—NIGHT**
>
> *LAURENA’S gown changes to a nightdress. She is walking slowly downstairs, a supernatural wind blowing.*
>
> **KAMA (V.O.)**
>   
> Lestrange used the Imperius Curse to seduce and abduct her . . .
>
> *The twelve-year-old KAMA runs after his mother, tugs at her hand, and tries to pull her back upstairs. She throws him off. The front door flies open. LESTRANGE SR. stands at the foot of the garden path. LAURENA walks toward him. KAMA chases after her. LESTRANGE SR. points his wand at KAMA and sends him sprawling.*
>
> *LAURENA lies on the bed as IRMA carries a newborn swaddled in a blanket to LESTRANGE SR.*” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald (The Original Screenplay)*</sup></sub>

If this is true, while it may be unusual for a child not both born and raised in Britain to attend Hogwarts, this would prove is is indeed possible for a child not born in Britain to attend.